# large if else statement in php

Tags: php, laravel

only fist two line execute in this code last two role not check how can solve this problem

```
$input = $request->all();
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);
        if(auth()->attempt(['email'=>$input["email"], 'password'=>$input['password']]))
        {
            
            
            if(auth()->user()->role == 'accountadmin')
            {
                return redirect()->route('accountadmins');
            }

            else if(auth()->user()->role == 'maintainadmin')
            {
                return redirect()->route('maintainadmins');
            }

            if(auth()->user()->role == 'superadmin')
            {
                return redirect()->route('superadmins');
            }

            if(auth()->user()->role == 'subscriber')
            {
                return redirect()->route('subscriberss');
            }


            else
            {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()
            ->route("login")
            ->with("error",'Incorrect email or password');
        }
```

```
if(auth()->user()->role == 'superadmin')
            {
                return redirect()->route('superadmins');
            }

            if(auth()->user()->role == 'subscriber')
            {
                return redirect()->route('subscriberss');
            }
```

without checking this role go next step. i have four login role using auth . but when i execute the only first two role check after that go next step . i try to else if else if but same problem

Comment: Can you check the role of the user's which are failing and show the user and the role.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) control structure here. Like this:

```
switch (auth()->user()->role) {
    case 'accountadmin'  : return redirect()->route('accountadmins');
    case 'maintainadmin' : return redirect()->route('maintainadmins');
    case 'superadmin'    : return redirect()->route('superadmins');
    case 'subscriber'    : return redirect()->route('subscribers');
    default              : return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: Not sure if op is saying there is a problem with the code or how to shorten it

Comment: @NigelRen I think he simply wants less code to do the nested if statements for permission checking.

Comment: @NigelRen: This is not an attempt at shortening the code, it's an alternative for a complicated `if (...) { ... } elseif (...) { .... } else { ....}` which the OP says doesn't work properly.

Comment: I've asked them to clarify what the data is that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although its much better to use `middlewares` or `route -> permission binding`, but to simply answer your question you can do the following:

```
$routes = [
    'accountadmins' => 'accountadmin',
    'maintainadmins' => 'maintainadmin',
    'superadmins' => 'superadmin',
    'subscribers' => 'subscriber'
];
```

**Using array_search:**

```
if (false !== $route = array_search(auth()->user()->role, $routes)) {
    return redirect()->route($route);
} else {
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Personally I recommend to use a permission package such as `spatie/laravel-permission` it is very well maintained and documented:

1. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/middleware#package-middleware
2. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: You don't need the `foreach` loop, you can just test if `auth()->user()->role` exists as a key in the array and then use the value.

Comment: hi @KIKOSoftware can you check my option 2, do you think that approach is better than loops/cases? It is honestly for my own self-learning process :)

Comment: Yes, I think it is better, but not with `array_search()`. Why to get the key first: `$role = auth()->user()->role;`, then test if it exists: `if (isset($routes[$role])) { .... } else { .... }`? I also renamed `$roles` to `$routes` because that's what the values represent, and `$key` to `$role`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Appreciate your feedback, thank you, I will do more research on php array processing, its been a while.

Comment: You're welcome. The idea of using an array is a good one.